# Log web service start/stop

Tags: c#, .net

How can I log .net web service restarted or stop within web service code

Comment: You may want to describe why you want to do this, since the nature of the way Web Services (ASP.NET Web Services) is such that start and stop may not be what you really want or use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you are talking about the web service application as a whole, check the Global.asax file.  You can add logging code in the Application_Start and Application_End events.

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
  void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    // Code that runs on application startup
    // Add logging here
  }

  void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    //  Code that runs on application shutdown
    // Add logging here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `onStart` and `OnStop` events. Sample code [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa529311.aspx).